# Excluir usuário firebase do banco e da autenticação

Tags: java, android, firebase

Boa tarde estou tentando fazer o método que exclui o usuário do banco e da autenticação,porém não está funcionando.

```java
private void excluirDeslogar(){

        final DialogProgress dialogProgress = new DialogProgress();
        dialogProgress.show(getFragmentManager(), "3");
        
        String emailUsuarioLogado = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();

         reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();

     reference.child("usuarios").orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailUsuarioLogado).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
            public void onDataChange( @NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    final Musico musico = postSnapshot.getValue(Musico.class);

                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    
                    //abaixo é o código que exclui do autenticação
                    firebaseUser.delete()
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        dialogMensagem("Sucesso", "Sucesso ao EXCLUIR usuário");

                                    } else {

                                        dialogMensagem("Erro", "Erro ao EXCLUIR usuário");

                                        reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();
                                        reference.child("Usuarios").child(musico.getuId()).removeValue();

                                        firebaseAuth.signOut();
                                        abrirTelaLogin();


                                    }

                                }
                            });
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        }




        private void abrirTelaLogin(){

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Login.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

não acredito que irá funcionar.
ao usar o método currentUser.delete() ele desloga do firebase auth sendo assim não necessita o signOut manualmente. ao deslogar você perde o token do auth e também não será mais possível realizar ler/escrever no firestore, a menos que as regras estejam totalmente inseguras.

O método mais indicado e seguro para realizar tal tarefa é automatizar uma no firebase functions e usar o firebase admin sdk para realizar a tarefa

```
exports.ondeleteuser = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
  // admin.firestore...
});
```

existe também uma própria extensão que já realizar isto para você automaticamente sem precisar de escrever sua cloud function: https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/delete-user-data?hl=pt-br